# Why is this called multiplication?

Tags: vector-spaces

This is in a paper I am reading. Let $V$ be a symplectic free module of rank 2 over the finite ring $Z_n.$ And let $H = V \times Z_n$ with multiplication given by $(v, z) \cdot (v', z') = (v + v', z + z' + \frac{1}{2}\omega (v, v'))$ where $\omega$ is the standard skew symmetric form of $V.$ Why is this called multiplication and how does it relate to the standard multiplication we normally see?

Comment: my first though is it might be related to the type of product formed ? example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product etc.

Comment: This is the way you define a Heisenberg group https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group Why is it called multiplication? Because it does define a group structure on $H$. The ``standard" multiplication gives an abelian group structure on $H$, while the Heisenberg group is not commutative.